# JAVA: I'm trying to make Connect4 game based on 2D array and graphics with swing

Tags: java, swing, multidimensional-array, graphics, indexoutofboundsexception

Backend program works with scanner input and just printing out the matrix, but I have this problem with graphics. When I'm making just rectangles with ovals inside them works good, but when I introduce 2D array into the story so that where I drop the piece fills with other color throws "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6". I tried putting it in different places and calling it in other sequences but it always throws this exception

EDIT: This is just a prototype code, much more work needs to be done, but I need to work this error to go on.

Full stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at GameLoop$DrawBoard.paintComponent(GameLoop.java:69)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5217)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1579)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1502)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1042)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:79)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:116)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1975)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3904)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:842)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

/**
 * Author : Matija & Zvonimir 
 * Version : 1.0
 * Purpose : Connect 4 game work. Creating working game with arrays
 *           
 *
*/
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class GameLoop extends JFrame{
   // attributes
   private int [][] matrix;
   int col;
   int row;
   private boolean gameOver = false;
   private int playerTurn = 0;

   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   //constants
   private static final int COL = 7;
   private static final int ROWS = 6;

   public static final int SQUARE_SIZE = 100;
   public static final int WIDTH = COL * SQUARE_SIZE;
   public static final int HEIGHT = (ROWS+1) * SQUARE_SIZE;
   public static final int CIRCLE_WIDTH_HEIGHT = (SQUARE_SIZE) - 15;

   //MAIN METHOD
   public static void main(String []args){      

      GameLoop gl = new GameLoop();
      //gl.gameOver();

   }//main

   /*GRAPHICS*/  
   private class DrawBoard extends JPanel{      

      int[][] board = new int[ROWS][COL];

      public DrawBoard(){

         for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < COL; j++){
               board[i][j] = 0;
            }         
         }//set to 0;
      }      


      public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

         super.paintComponents(g); //override  

         for(int i = 0; i < COL; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++){

               g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
               g.fillRect( (i*SQUARE_SIZE),(j * SQUARE_SIZE+SQUARE_SIZE),SQUARE_SIZE,SQUARE_SIZE);     

               if(board[i][j] == 0){
                  g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                  g.fillOval( (i*SQUARE_SIZE),(j*SQUARE_SIZE +SQUARE_SIZE),CIRCLE_WIDTH_HEIGHT,CIRCLE_WIDTH_HEIGHT);                  

               }else if(board[i][j] == 1){

                  g.setColor(Color.RED);
                  g.fillRect( (i*SQUARE_SIZE),(j * SQUARE_SIZE+SQUARE_SIZE),SQUARE_SIZE,SQUARE_SIZE);                     

               }else if(board[i][j] == 2){ 

                  g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                  g.fillOval( (i*SQUARE_SIZE),(j*SQUARE_SIZE +SQUARE_SIZE),CIRCLE_WIDTH_HEIGHT,CIRCLE_WIDTH_HEIGHT);

               }
            }
         }     

         for(int i = 0; i < COL; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++){


            }//for J
         } //for I

      }//paint component method  

   }//CLASS


   public GameLoop(){            

      DrawBoard board = new DrawBoard();      

      add(board);
      setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      setPreferredSize( new Dimension(701,732));
      //setResizable(false);
      setLocation( 400,200 );
      setVisible ( true );
      pack();    

   }

   /*
    * Method that creates a 2d array (matrix) filled with 0s
    * @param matrix 2d array
    */ 
   public int[][] createBoard(){
      matrix = new int[ROWS][COL];

      for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < COL; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
         }         
      }//set to 0

      return matrix;

   }//create board       


}//class game loop
```

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace

Comment: I posted it @JeroenSteenbeeke

Comment: Make the effort and post [mcve]  (while making one it is most likely that you find the problem yourself)

Comment: Ok, I will , tnx @c0der

Comment: Mark line #69 in the code (where error is generated). I guess it is  ` `for(int i = 0; i < COL; i++)`  which should be `for(int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)`

Comment: Yes man, that's it, thank you very much! @c0der

Comment: For future posts note that [mcve] is very helpful to you as well as to those who try to help. Also when you post `at GameLoop$DrawBoard.paintComponent(GameLoop.java:69)` mark line 69 with a comment so we know on which line the error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing row and columns when indexing board[]

```
     for(int i = 0; i < COL; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++){

           g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
           g.fillRect( (i*SQUARE_SIZE),(j * SQUARE_SIZE+SQUARE_SIZE),SQUARE_SIZE,SQUARE_SIZE);     

           if(board[i][j] == 0){
              g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
              g.fillOval( (i*SQUARE_SIZE),(j*SQUARE_SIZE +SQUARE_SIZE),CIRCLE_WIDTH_HEIGHT,CIRCLE_WIDTH_HEIGHT);                  

           }else if(board[i][j] == 1){

              g.setColor(Color.RED);
              g.fillRect( (i*SQUARE_SIZE),(j * SQUARE_SIZE+SQUARE_SIZE),SQUARE_SIZE,SQUARE_SIZE);                     

           }else if(board[i][j] == 2){ 

              g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
              g.fillOval( (i*SQUARE_SIZE),(j*SQUARE_SIZE +SQUARE_SIZE),CIRCLE_WIDTH_HEIGHT,CIRCLE_WIDTH_HEIGHT);

           }
        }
     }
```

it should be board[j][i], or simply swap their roles in the loop statments